# codeigniter - Can't delete or modify database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my first time using codeigniter to build a site, so I'm pretty new to it. I have an admin page where videos can be approved or deleted and neither of the functions are working. When the links are clicked it just loads the page and nothing has happened, and there isn't any change in the database. I went here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data and tried this:

`$this->db->delete('files', array('id' => $id));`

It changes the url to what I believe is correct: `/profile/delete/29`

I'm loading the model which contains this simple function:

```
function delete($fileid){
    //$this->db->query("DELETE FROM files WHERE ID = '$fileid'");

    $this->db->delete('files', array('ID' => $fileid));
}
```

Then running this in my controller:

```
function delete($id){
    //$this->db->query("DELETE FROM files WHERE ID=$id");

    $this->files->delete($id);

    redirect('profile');
}
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using Unix/Linux, the problem might be case-sensitive row names. Also, there is no $this->load->model('files'); line in your code.

Comment: I was loading it at the top of the controller under `parent::__construct();`.

Comment: use $this->db->affedted_rows(); after the delete: it'll show you how many rows have been deleted. You may also use $this->db->last_query(); after the delete to know what query has been launched to the DDBB

Comment: Thank you for those, they're really useful. :)  I tried them on my test MVC and they worked, but not on my actual MVC that I'm trying this on. I threw some echo's in the delete function and nothing was displayed as if it's not even running the function. Perhaps some kind of code conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function delete($fileid){
    $this->db->where('ID', $fileid);
    $this->db->delete('files');
}



function delete($id){
   $this->load->model('files');

    $this->files->delete($id);

    redirect('profile');
}
```

If you have any error, just write it on comment.

Comment: I created a test controller, model and view with only the bare essentials and it worked. I copied the exact same code over (only changing the table name of course) and it didn't work. I'm not getting an error. Is there a way I can var_dump/echo/capture the data?

Comment: @stinkysGTI remove redirect and check if error will show!

Comment: Nothing. Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Check the ID (case-sensitive) and check if model file name is correct and the name of class too. Because, in this form it works at me.

Comment: All of that is correct. I also have an upload function in the same controller and it works just fine. I'm going to have to strip it way down and reverse debug it.